# How to store Audio files like MP3,WAV & AMR in Flash memory W25Q64FV(winbond)?

Tags: esp32, arduino-uno, spi, flash-memory

Need Help in storing Audio files (MP3, AMR, WAV) in 16MB flash memory and play using ESP32 wroom 32D, what's the software and programmer I need to use to store Audio files on W25Q64FV or similar winbond flash memory?

I am currently using Arduino IDE, I can detect SPI chip ID, using Basic Arduino SPI flash code.